# How to improve ListView's loading time faster?

Tags: android

I implemented my `ListView` using custom adapter extended from `ArrayAdapter`.
My problem is sometimes `ListView` is loaded slowly. That means a blank activity is loaded first without the `ListView`, then the `ListView` comes out. At worst case, I am prompted to "force closed or wait". I like to improve that slow loading as it is annoying to the user.

But sometimes, loading is fast and almost immediate.

But I like to make sure my `ListView` design is correct and the design does not have any problem with that slow loading. So that this discussion will be useful for other people who are facing the same problem as mine.

My ListView is designed as follow.

Each ListItem has three components, thumbnail image, ID text, and arrow image as shown in the figure attached [image].

In loading process of the `ListView`, (1)All ID text are retrieved from the database and populated into a ListArray `List<String> listIDs`

```
        public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
                dbHelper = new TrackerDBAdapter(getActivity());
                dbHelpLatLong = new LatLogDBAdapter(getActivity());
                dbHelpNotification = new NotificationDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
                dbHelper.open();
                Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllTrackerInTheList();
                listIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
                activationStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
                thisListFragmentContext = getActivity();
                for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
                     listIDs.add(cursor.getString(1));                   
                }
            dbHelper.close();

(2)Then my custom list adapter is called. 




        adapter = new customList_Adaptor(thisListFragmentContext,
                        R.layout.list_row, listIDs, this);
        }

That is the loading process inside my `ListFragment`.
```

(3) The following class is my custom `ArrayAdapter` and I implemented to load thumbnail `ImageView` using `AsyncTask`. My query are

(i)I still have retrieving ID text from database, and loading arrow image. Should I put those processes into `AsyncTask` as well?
(ii)If I need it, should I implement another `AsyncTask` or use the same `AsyncTask` used for thumbnail image loading?
(iii)Among these, which aspect of the program design I still can improve that is suspicious to my slow loading?

```
public class customList_Adaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


    protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
    private TrackerDBAdapter dbHelper;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> activationState = new ArrayList<String>();
    public MyListFragment mMyListFragment;
    public customList_Adaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects, List<String> activationStatus, MyListFragment mMyListFragment) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.setContext(context);
        this.listIDs = objects;
        this.activationState = activationStatus;
        this.mMyListFragment= mMyListFragment;
        dbHelper = new TrackerDBAdapter(context);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(listIDs != null)
            return listIDs.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(listIDs != null)
            return listIDs.get(arg0);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(vi==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.id=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.thumbnailImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            viewHolder.activationStatus = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.activated);
            //lazy load image
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(viewHolder.thumbnailImage);
            task.execute(position);

            viewHolder.arrow=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_arrow);
            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        viewHolder.thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new onMyClick(position));               
        // Setting all values in listview
        viewHolder.id.setText(listIDs.get(position));   

        if(activationState.get(position).equals("Not activated yet")){
             viewHolder.activationStatus.setText(activationState.get(position));
             viewHolder.activationStatus.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
        }
        else if(activationState.get(position).equals("Activated"))
            viewHolder.activationStatus.setText("");
        return vi;
    }

    public class onMyClick implements OnClickListener {

        private final int pos;
        public onMyClick(int pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyListFragment.clickedimageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);                      
            mMyListFragment.imagepos(pos);
        }

    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Lazy image update
    class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        private int data = 0;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            setData(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            dbHelper.open();
            Cursor mCursor = dbHelper.getImagebyIDnumber(getData());
            byte[] img_bytes = mCursor.getBlob(13);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img_bytes, 0, img_bytes.length);         

            dbHelper.close();        
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        public int getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

   }


public class ViewHolder {
      TextView id;
      TextView activationStatus;
      ImageView thumbnailImage;
      ImageView arrow;
}
```

Comment: I use database to save all contents of the ListItem. So retrieving the data from the database is the slow response in loading. So I tried to use AsyncTask to retrieve the ListItem contents. But the problem is, if the background process is still running at the time custom adapter is called, the ListView does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I did a few things to make it faster in loading the app.
I am not sure which one is the solution.
(1) I load all data from sql database including text and thumbnail images using `AsyncTask`.
(2) I change thumbnail image format from png to jpg.
(3) Then I clear the cache manually. 
The app looks like faster in loading, but sometimes it is still slow. Most of the times, it is faster than before.
I am still making improvement to my app.
Thanks

Comment: Now the problem is solved and the ListView can be loaded very fast. Now I coded clearing cache in the program onDestroy().